# Counting tokens in a document

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I would need to calculate the frequency for every token in the training data, making a list of the tokens which have a frequency at least equal to N.
To split my dataset into train and test I did as follows:

```
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Text'].replace(np.NaN, ""))

y=df['Label']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.30, stratify=y)
```

If `Text` column contains sentences, for example

```
Text
Show some code
Describe what you've tried
Have a non-programming question?
More helpful links
```

to extract all tokens I did as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

X_train['tokenized_text'] = X_train.Text.apply(lambda row: word_tokenize(row))
```

This gives me tokens locally, and not globally. I should have the all list and count through all the rows, in order to make a list of the tokens which have a frequency at least equal to `N`.
My difficulties are in counting the frequency of tokens through all the column.

Could you please tell me how to count these tokens?

UPDATE:

The following code works fine:

```
df.Text.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

however I don't know how to extract all the words/tokens having count > 15, for example.

Comment: Can you please show the expected output ? and what is your tokenized_text, BTW I am not the one downvote u ~

Comment: Thanks BEN_YO. so tokenised_text should be a new column (I do not know if I can do it in my training dataset. The problem is that I should consider these tokenised words in my training dataset in order to use them as features. My expected output would me a list of words counted through all the dataset (in what I posted as example all the tokens have count 1 - unfortunately ). I should select as features, after creating this list, only those tokens/words which have a count value greater than a threshold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you say the following works fine

```
s = df.Text.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

Then you can do

```
s[s>=15].index
```

to get the tokens with at least `15` counts.

However, the first line doesn't give the same tokenization with `nltk.word_tokenize`. If you want the latter's output, you can replace the first line with:

```
s = df.Text.apply(lambda row: word_tokenize(row)).explode().value_counts()
```

which gives the following from your sample data:

```
Have               1
you                1
what               1
a                  1
Describe           1
've                1
non-programming    1
tried              1
some               1
code               1
?                  1
links              1
Show               1
helpful            1
More               1
question           1
Name: Text, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks a lot Quang Hoang, also for the spot about the different results!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Counter collection to perform what you need and than create a secondary list only with the words that are filtered according to your the limit. Check the code below as an example with limit 2:

```
from collections import Counter
test_list = ["test", "test", "word", "hello"]

counter = Counter(test_list)
filtered_counter = {k:v for k, v in counter.items() if v >= 2}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Rafael Américo Sartori. just a question: would it be work also for a column (maybe using .apply)? I would need to work with column as I need to use the extracted words/tokens as features for my classifier

Comment: I tried with this: `c = Counter()
df.Text.str.split().apply(c.update)` but I got all `None`